# Замыкание в PHP

Tags: php

Наткнулся на такую необычную конструкцию, ранее нигде не видел:

```
$variable = function($any) use ($alternate_var, &$yet)
{
 /// Any code
};
```

Как работает данная конструкция, особо интересно это `use ($alternate_var, &$yet)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829544/what-is-the-use-for-the-argument-block-in-anonymous-functions/27829610#27829610

Comment: принцип работы конструкции use забавный, это есть в примерах в офф мануале, об анонимных функциях и в комментраиях

Answer (score 5):

[Читать](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php).
`callback`-функция это.
Т. е. когда нужна функция, но лень/другая_причина создавать отдельную функцию, которую один раз как параметр передашь.
По решению Свыше, у них нет доступа к родительской области видимости, поэтому используется `use` как метод передачи переменных в локальный контекст `callback`-функции.

```
$a = 1;
$b = [5];
array_map(function($q){
    print $a;
}, $b);
// Undefined variable: a

$a = 1;
$b = [5];
array_map(function($q) use ($a){
    print $a;
}, $b);
// 1
```

**Важно**:
Конструкция `use` передаёт **значение**, а не **ссылку**. Т. е. изменение переданной переменной не повлияет на родительскую переменную. Если это необходимо, используйте `&`:

```
$a = 1;
$b = [5];
array_map(function($q) use (&$a){
    print $a;
    $a = 2;
}, $b);
print $a;
// 12
```

Comment: так а в чем разница между обычными аргументами и конструкцией `use`

Comment: @MaximPro, Аргументы в анонимную функцию устанавливает потом и кто-то (`array_map`, например, передаст аргументами значения массива), а доступ к родительской области видимости так не передашь. Вот и используют `use`.

Comment: вроде бы понятно и непонятно

Comment: @MaximPro, что именно Вам непонятно?

Comment: как мы можем установить аргументы в анонимную функцию если мы не положили это в переменную? всмысле это `array_map(function($q) use (&$a){
    print $a;
    $a = 2;
}, $b);`

Comment: @MaximPro, Я слегка Вас не понял. Всё логично - аргумент `$q` даёт нам доступ до очередного элемента, который даёт нам `array_map`. "Ручками" мы установить его не можем. К области видимости он никакого отношения не имеет. А `&$a` просто как проход в родительскую область к `$a`. В аргумент мы его не можем поставить, ибо вдруг будет 2 или больше аргументов (а так и есть)? Нет, лучше не мешать аргументы и область видимости, целее нервы будут.

Comment: теперь вообще ничего непонятно X_X

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43807/discussion-between-other-and-maximpro).

Comment: Дякую за толкове пояснення, бо в оф доках мало що зрозуміло! Гарно розписали і пояснили!

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном примере используется анонимная функция с наследованием переменной из родительской области видимости. (Подробнее [http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php#example-199))

Статья на хабре про применение замыканий в PHP [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/147620/).

Пример:

```
$alternate_var = 'world';
$yet = '!';

$variable = function($any) use ($alternate_var, &$yet)
{
    return $any . $alternate_var . $yet;
};

echo $variable('Hello ');    // Hello world!
```